# Where to put things in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, package, laravel-5.1, portability

I'm a bit confused about where something like this belongs to Laravel.

I want to write a web service client wrapper in laravel, and I want to access it like this:

```
\MyWSClient::getSomeInfoAbout($someId);
```

then the code will connect to the web service to http://www.someapi.com/api/getSomeInfoAbout?id=$someid&type=json with OAuth2 or some token requests, then fetch the data, keep token information until it expires, refresh token if needed etc.

But where will I put the code? In the `vendor` directory as a new package? I'm moving this code from a computer to another computer except `vendor`,`storage` and `node_modules` folders, because they are huge and when I do this, I will have to move only one folder in the vendor directory. And I'll need to publish a package under development to composer if I want portability etc.

Is there any other way to do something like this?

Comment: just add your code in folder to your root project folder . then register the folder to your composer folder .

Comment: Now I'm trying it. I've created a packages folder beside the vendor folder, and trying to create a package in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer.

First I needed to use `jeroen-g/laravel-packager` package to create a new package using artisan console. I could've done that by hand, but I didn't know the required files.

Second, I've created a new package in the `packages` folder with my desired class name.

Third, I've added the provider and the alias for the class in `app.php`.

After that, I've created a test method in my controller and wrote a route for that. I called the static method I've written in the `SkeletonClass` the packager created for me.

And it worked with some tweaking after creation.

I've used `php artisan packager:new tpaksu mypackage --i` command for an interactive package creation which is cool.

**Note:** I've just learned the existence of this package, I'm not advertising it :)